default nettype only for inputs
Is it possible to have wire as default for inputs, but not default declare module internal signals?
As I understand `default_nettype` controls

port kind of input and inout ports (As discussed in Question Implicit net-type declaration and `default-nettype)
kind for signals in the design (for example logic)

Example, setting `default_nettype wire makes this code
module m1 (
   input  logic i1,
   output logic o1
   );

   logic  l1;
   assign l1 = i1;
   assign o1 = l1;
endmodule

mean the same thing as:
module m1 (
   input  wire logic i1,    // <-- default wire
   output logic o1
   );

   wire logic l1;          // <-- default wire
   assign l1 = i1;
   assign o1 = l1;
endmodule

Is there some setting that allows input to get default nettype wire but still cause failure in the case when an undefined signal is used:
module m1 (
   input  logic i1,   // <-- let this one default to wire
   output logic o1
   );

   logic  l1;
   logic banana;
   assign l1 = i1;
   assign hanana = i1;   // typo, should give error since no default declaration
   assign o1 = l1;
endmodule


No, your only choice for a default input net type is  `default_nettype.

Without the directive, input  logic i1 always makes i1 a net, with a implicit nettype of wire. Had you used  `default_nettype tri1, i1 would have had made the nettype tri1.
Unfortunately, the  `default_nettype none directive does not distinguish between levels on implicitness. Your best options is to be fully explicit with input wire logic i1
Otherwise, you can downgrade this error to a warning.
